# Bounty award on unanswered confirmed dupes

Tags: discussion, bounties

I have found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17292898/delete-option-on-fineuploader) which is most probably [a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5010201/resolving-this-operation-requires-iis-integration-pipeline-mode-in-asp-net-mvc). There is a bounty of 50 rep (not much I know..)

Is still would be interested in what happens, if none answers the question, but it is flagged and confirmed as duplicate

Comment: A question cannot be closed while it has an active bounty on it.

Comment: *What happens if there's no answer after the bounty period?* is specifically addressed in the linked FAQ.

Comment: so there is no duplicate linking, which might award the bounty to an answer of the original question, as the question cannot be closed. correct?

Comment: The bounty would never be awarded to an answer on the dupe, no.